# CR LF replacement in Unity Input Fields when copy and pasting

Tags: unity, c#, input

I setup a bit of code to detect line breaks using `\n` char (line feed), from the `TMPro_InputField`:

```
foreach(char c in text)
{
    if (c == '\n')  { splitLines.Add(cur);  cur = ""; }
    else {cur += c;}
}
```

When only characters are pressed directly into the input field, things worked great, but when I pasted in text from notepad, the results are confusing. After a ton of debugging I realize that Windows use CRLF (carriage return + line feed combo), so I simply use `Replace()` to sort things out.

Problems arise when the user copy and paste. If I implement a copy button, then I can replace `"\n"` with `"\r\n"` manually:

```
public void copyFromText()
{
    TextEditor textEditor = new TextEditor();
    textEditor.text = textField.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
    textEditor.text = textEditor.text.Replace("\n", "\r\n"); //this line here
    textEditor.SelectAll();
    textEditor.Copy();
}
```

Same goes for pasting. But when user press `Ctrl+C` or `Ctrl+V`, things get complicated. I could detect keys pressed, check if input field is highlighted, and replace stuff by hand, etc... but that's too much of a nuisance.

Is there a way to resolve this quicker? Or better, just config Unity to use CR LF with input fields somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use #define directives?(https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

So when on Windows UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
Or on windows editor UNITY_EDITOR_WIN
Then always replace with CR LF

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I'm new to Unity and not sure how to do this.

Comment: Actually it just works on my windows machine. Did you selected on the TextMeshProInputField: Line Type: "Multi Line Newline"? RichText needs t be checked too.

<pre><code>
    private void ConvertLineEndings()
        {
    #if UNITY_EDITOR_WIN ||UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
        _tMP_InputField.SetTextWithoutNotify(_tMP_InputField.text.Replace("\n", "\u000a"));
    #endif
        }</pre></code>

Comment: `\u000a` is newline...? What's its difference between `\n` and `\r` and it? And as the main question stated, what can I do if user press `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V` instead?